# How can I align question/answer text in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, alignment

I am aware you can have a similar effect with using tabs, which I've tried to set up below:[image]

But, as you can see, if the answer is longer than others, the text alignment gets messed up.(Tabs can be frustrating!)

I am wondering if there is another way to align a question & answer - maybe have separate columns, or have 2 separate text boxes that will have the question and answer line up to each other, no matter how long the answer may be.

Any suggestions?

Comment: create a [table](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/creating-tables.html)?

Comment: I'm flagging to close this question as tech support, since the solution is in the software manual.

Comment: @Luciano I disagree. I am a rather advanced user of ID, and I'm curious after this answer. And, who *does* read a manual these days?

Comment: by _read the manual_ I mean _google the issue and find it in the Adobe Indesign website_ ;)

Comment: By *who reads the manual* I mean *who can understand the wall of spaghetti-text that is the Adobe Indesign website* ;P

Comment: Create a table.  Top align the text in each cell.

Comment: I'd suggest that the majority of questions on this site could be answered by a manual, though individual circumstances make the application of the information in the manual unclear, so questions are asked and we endeavour to answer them.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking to do here is to make a table, where the rows expand, keeping your content aligned. Luckily InDesign has such a feature. Make a new text box roughly the size of you're whole Q&A area, then insert the table from:

> Table > Insert Table (cmnd/ctrl + alt + shift + T)

The column number will be 2 (one for questions, one for answers) and your row number will be the number of questions you have. You can always insert more rows (or even columns) later. No need to put header or footer rows)

This will insert a table of default-sized cells, with black borders. You can colour the borders if you like by applying a stroke, though it seems like you shouldn't need to do that and you're just using it to align text, so select all the cells with the text tool, then remove the stroke on the toolbar at the top of Indesign, or in the stroke panel.

Next adjust the widths of the columns to those that make sense for the lengths of your Qs and As. Play about with them until they're right. It works much like when inserting a table on Word, except that it is constrained within a text box.